# Netgear R7000 router lags when connecting to VPN

Tags: networking, router, vpn

I just bought a new Netgear Nighthawk R7000 router to use on my 100Mbps cable broadband connection. Download speeds and upload speeds look fine except when I VPN into my work's intranet. On my old Linksys WRT54G router, I never had issues, but on this new router, there is considerable lag. For example when I remote desktop into a work computer, there is a lot of delay when typing in documents on that computer (i.e. I type and it takes seconds for the words to appear). Sometimes the remote computer is responsive, but often there is a delay.

Is there some setting I don't have right on my router? Here is my setup

1. Netgear cm500-100NAS cable modem
2. Netgear AC1900 R7000 router
3. HP laptop with 1000Gbit ethernet connected to router by ethernet cable
4. Juniper networks VPN client running on computer to connect to work intranet